# iPhone displaying data similar to a school timetable

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

How can i display data similar to a school timetable? so the table view has multiple rows. I have been searching for a tutorial/information about this but haven't had any luck =/. Thanks for any help

Comment: a `school timetable`? multiple rows isn't very descriptive.  find a picture, post to pastebin and link to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you mean multiple columns. If so I would use a view for every column and subview of these view for every row.